# How can I get an integer index for a key in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

Intuitively, hadoop is doing something like this to distribute keys to mappers, using python-esque pseudocode.

```
# data is a dict with many key-value pairs
keys = data.keys()
key_set_size = len(keys) / num_mappers
index = 0
mapper_keys = []
for i in range(num_mappers):
  end_index = index + key_set_size
  send_to_mapper(keys[int(index):int(end_index)], i)
  index = end_index
# And something vaguely similar for the reducer (but not exactly).
```

It seems like somewhere hadoop knows the index of each key it is passing around, since it distributes them evenly among the mappers (or reducers).  My question is: how can I access this index?  I'm looking for a range of integers [0, n) mapping to all my n keys; this is what I mean by an "index".

I'm interested in the ability to get the index from within either the mapper or reducer.

Comment: Why are you interested in the key? (not saying there isn't a valid reason, however, a major point of MapReduce lays in the fact that you don't know anything about the data source in the mapper, as they simply transform input into some sort of output, independently from each other).

Comment: My ultimate goal is to build a reverse lookup index where keys are contiguous integers and the values are larger objects, such as urls.  This can be thought of as similar to (but not exactly the same as) building a Huffman encoding scheme.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: Wouldn't that need some data structure accessable by all mapper/reducer? I think you are looking into the wrong architecture for your intention, MapReduce is build upon the fact that there is no concurrent access or knowledge between the mappers. Also, the input isn't read by the master, it just pushes blocks (usually 64mb) of data to the mappers, which gets read independently. So there is no global id for a datastructure.

Comment: Thanks, @Femaref.  I will interpret your answer as "that data isn't available," which does answer my question.

Comment: Plenty of good reasons to want to look at a file line number... For instance, so you can go into the file and go to the right line to look at the data...

Comment: Not saying it isn't available @Tyler, you could easily generate a global id with a sequential mapper (that is, just one), use the line number, or similar. However, you might be circumventing assumptions of MapReduce, which could create additional problems, especially when you start depending on ids being processed sequentially by the same mapper in future MapReduce steps, which might not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research on this question, I don't believe it is possible to do exactly what I want. Hadoop does not seem to have such an index that is user-visible after all, although it does try to distribute work evenly among the mappers (so such an index is theoretically possible).

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your reducer (each individual one) gets an array of items back that correspond to the reduce key. So do you want the offset of items within the reduce key in your reducer, or do you want the overall offset of the particular item in the global array of all lines being processed? To get an indeex in your mapper, you can simply prepend a line number to each line of the file before the file gets to the mapper. This will tell you the "global index". However keep in mind that with 1 000 000 items, item 662 345 could be processed before item 10 000.

Comment: I care about a global index, not per-reducer.  Though if I can get a reducer index and a per-reducer index, maybe I could hack a fake version of a global index out of that.  Can I get those two things?

Comment: Just use a line number, or if for example you are dumping a db table with an auto inc key.. use the auto inc key...

Comment: Of course, your mapper could be processing multiple files. So the idea of a "global index" across multiple files kind of doesn't make sense...

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the new MR API then the **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.HashPartitioner** is the default partitioner or else **org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.HashPartitioner** is the default partitioner. You can call the **getPartition()** on either of the HashPartitioner to get the partition number for the key (which you mentioned as index).

*Note that the HashPartitioner class is only used to distribute the keys to the Reducer. When it comes to a mapper, each input split is processed by a map task and the keys are not distributed.*

Here is the code from HashPartitioner for the getPartition(). You can write a simple Java program for the same.

> public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
>   return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
>   }

**Edit:** Including another way to get the index.

The following code [from](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-find-partition-number-in-reducer-td20927911.html) should also work. To be included in the map or the reduce function.

> public void configure(JobConf job) {
>   partition = job.getInt( "mapred.task.partition", 0);
>   }

Comment: "I'm looking for a range of integers [0, n) mapping to all my n keys; this is what I mean by an "index" - I mentioned that there is no such mapping for the map tasks and there is HashPartitioner for the reduce tasks. I think the answer is proper.

Comment: I found some docs for these classes (link below), but I don't understand how to get an index from them.  Will the return value of getPartition() will be unique per key?  The usual setup for hash values gives no guarantee of contiguous hash values, though (in fact, almost the opposite, they are often spread out).  Also, if this is after all a way to get an index for a key, how would I actually call this function?  Just create my own HashPartitioner object and call getPartition on it?

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/HashPartitioner.html

Comment: The hash values are spread, but because the module operation is done on them the index for a key is not spread out and is contained between 0 and (# of reducers - 1). Either call this function or perform the same calculation in a map or reduce task. The map and the reduce functions are passed the key and you can call the JobConf.getNumReduceTasks() for the # of reduce tasks.